# iptables Couldn't load target `SSH'

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables

I'm having a little problem with `iptables`. I am trying to make this command work but it gives me an error. I need some help, thanks.

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22000 -m state --state NEW -j SSH
iptables v1.6.1: Couldn't load target `SSH':No such file or directory
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

The rule is for allowing the access to the ssh service running in the port 22000/tcp.
Later I will add this command to allow the access from this computer:

```
$ sudo iptables -A SSH -s 19.168.10.201 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: What is `SSH` supposed to be there? Did you mean something like `-j DROP` to drop new connections? What is this rule supposed to do?

Comment: The rule is for allowing the access to the ssh service running in the port 22000/tcp.
Later I will add this command to allow the access from this computer

    $ sudo iptables -A SSH -s 19.168.10.201 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Then you should add that chain first, before asking iptables to use that chain as a target.

Comment: Thank you so much! I missed that, now it's working! I created it with "$ iptables -N ssh"

Comment: Excellent, you can post that as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot creating the chain first. I fixed it with the command:

```
$ sudo iptables -N SSH
```

Thanks to muru!